# Where does the Link death sound from Mario Maker 2 originate?

Tags: game-music-identification, legend-of-zelda-series, super-mario-maker-2

In SMB1 mode in Mario Maker 2, there are multiple powerups that change Mario into a character from a different game: the SMB 2 mushroom, the Mario Land superball flower, and the Master Sword that turns Mario into Link.  These powerups also change the background music and various sound effects to be more consistent with their associated games, with a very high level of fidelity to the original source material.

There's one very noticeable exception, though: [when the player dies as Link,](https://youtu.be/F1nAI_rAotg?t=1469) a sound is played that is somewhat similar to [Link's death sound from *The Legend of Zelda*](https://youtu.be/MXzR3aTUhwY?t=6) but distinctly different from it.  In fact, this sound doesn't appear to match any Link death sounds from any NES or SNES Zelda game.

Where does this strange death sound originally come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's Link's death sound from the Famicom Disk System version of Legend of Zelda. You can hear a comparison here:

The Famicom Disk System had extra hardware for audio, and some games, like Zelda, made use of the extra audio channel, resulting in a different sound to the cartridge based port that was released in the west.

Comment: That's a very interesting video.  Thanks for the identification!